# PyCharm's extract method seems broken : no return variables created

Tags: python, pycharm

There seem to be a weird bug in PyCharm: when I "extract method", the new method doesn't return anything although it should as the refactored code generates an output which is reused. Earlier, it was properly working. I noticed that it might have to do with passing lists as references and appending to them instead of returning the values properly and directly. But on the same code, one of my peers tried to extract the same thing as a method and his PyCharm IDE seemed to work correctly and has put return values to his extracted method. We both change nothing in the popup window and accept the default and complete refactoring settings prompted upon extracting the method.

Is there a setting to change this default behaviour? How to repair the IDE?

Comment: Show the code pre- and post-extraction, otherwise it's impossible to even guess what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, I can't.